# access config from $http.get in angular js in rest api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http-get

This is the code I am using to pass data using config in http get in angular js.

```
app.controller("users", function($scope,  $http, $routeParams,    $route,$window){
$scope.role_name = $window.role_name;
  var config = {
       params: 
       {
           'session' : session['email']
       }
  }
  $http.get("http://localhost:5000/users",config   ).success(function(response){
      $scope.users = response;
  });       
});
```

This is the code in the rest api:

```
@api.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_users():

    if 'session' in request.json:
        try:
            result = sys.get_users_client(request.json['session'])
        except:
            abort(503,'not logged in')
        else :
            return jsonify_list(result)
```

here how do I access the params in config so that I can use the 'session' passed in it.

Comment: what result do you get when you `print(request.json)`?

Comment: Seems like nothing is being sent. Could you try something as simple as: `$http.get("http://localhost:5000/users", [param: 1])` and see if that prints anything?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh I tried it, but it's still showing None  :(

Comment: At this point, I suggest setting a breakpoint on the API side on the line: `if 'session' in request.json:`. Then inspect the *request object* and see if you can find the parameters you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass that in header or as query string and I am pretty sure each rest api allow you to access request header and request query string. By looking at ur code ur passing query string in $http.get so you need to access current request querystring in ur api.

By looking at ur code and if it is python u can get querystring as below

```
>>> request.geturl()

>>> url = urlparse(request.geturl())
>>> url.query
```

Comment: Check documentation. You can send a config item with the GET call `get(url, [config])`. Check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

Comment: I tried to pass it as a header, but I am not able to access that header in rest api...

Comment: @SylvanDAsh Yes, but how do I access the data in config in the rest api ?

Comment: I'm personally not that conversant with Python (so not sure if the config is in the `json` object) but I'd say you first start by sending a simple param and see if you can get that. Probably also search getting params in REST API for Python

Comment: did my answer help??